# How do we define the tensor functor

Tags: category-theory, definition

In my course, the teacher defines the tensor functor $$-\otimes-:\text{Mod}_K\times \text{Mod}_K\rightarrow \text{Mod}_K : (M,N)\mapsto M\otimes N$$ but he does not define how the functor acts on functions $f:(M,N)\rightarrow (M',N')$

How could one define this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By
$$(f\otimes g)(x\otimes y) = f(x)\otimes g(y)\ .$$

Comment: To be clear, $f: M \to M'$, $g: N \to N'$ right? Or is it, $f:(M,N) \to (M', N')$, $g: (M',N') \to (M'',N'')$

Comment: @mtheorylord yes, the first version.